# How to avoid banding with raymarched fog?

Tags: hlsl, fragment-shader, raymarching

I have a raymarching shader for fog.
It works well but It creates artifacts in the form of banding:

[image]

I understand the problem: The step size is too large and the sample points above the ground are not hitting the floor until the distance is bigger again.

However, How can this be reduced/ avoided?

My Shader looks like this:

```
float4 PS(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET {
    float3 rayStart = input.WorldPos.xyz;
    float3 viewDirection = normalize(input.WorldPos.xyz-CamPositionWS.xyz);
    float depth = linearize_depth(DepthTexture.Sample(DepthSampler, input.UV).x, NearPlane, FarPlane);
    float4 result = float4(FogColor, 0);
    float stepSize = 300;
    float stepAmount = ((NoiseTexture.Sample(Sampler, input.UV * 64).x)) * 64;
    [unroll(96)]
    while (stepAmount < depth) {
        float3 samplePos = rayStart + (viewDirection*stepAmount);
        stepAmount += stepSize;
        float fogDist = distance(samplePos, FogCenter);
        if (fogDist > FogRadius)
            continue;
        result.a += density(fogDist,FogRadius)*FogDensity;
        if (result.a >= 1) {
            result.a = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    result = saturate(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Dithering can be a powerful tool for combatting banding in low-contrast gradients. [See this talk on rendering for Inside that shows details of this technique](https://gdcvault.com/play/1023783/Low-Complexity-High-Fidelity-INSIDE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of increasing your sample depth by `stepSize` every time, why not divide `depth` by `floor(depth/stepSize)` and incrementing by that? That will give you *n* evenly-spaced sample points between camera and the surface.

Then the step length will vary slightly to give the same number of samples on proximate points.

It would still give you a transition as the number of sample points increases (say your stepSize is `1` by default and depth transitions from `4.999` to `5.0`, you'd go from 4 sample points at `1.25`, `2.5`, `3.75`, `4.999` to 5 points on integers 1-5, but assuming your fog is homogenous, that shouldn't be too jarring.

Let's say we want a sample every 1 unit by default, then look at some different depths: 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6

- 4.0: 1, 2, 3, 4 [4 samples, 1 unit step]
- 4.5: 1.125, 2.25, 3.375, 4.5 [4 samples, 1.125 unit step]
- 5.0: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 [5 samples, 1 unit step]
- 5.5: 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5 [5 samples, 1.1 unit step]
- 6.0: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 [6 samples, 1 unit step]

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the step size becomes insanely huge when the depth value becomes larger? https://i.imgur.com/G2hHnbx.jpg.
If my character is in the fog in a large open area, my character will be completely foggy but the environment wont.

Comment: No as we're using the same number of samples, just stretching them out a little bit before you get to the transition to _more_ samples. See my edit, is that any clearer?

Comment: I was in a situation where the depth was not available, but adding 10% of noise to the stepsize was enough to create some very cheap dither and completely eliminate banding